# How does import sum from './sum' differ from var sum = require('./sum')?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**sum.js**

```
const sum = (a: number, b: number): number => {
  return a + b;
}

export default sum;
```

**sum.test.js**

```
// var sum = require('../sum');  // doesn't work
import sum from '../sum';  // works

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Why does the `require()` fail but `import` works? I was under the impression that I could mix them / they did the same thing.

Comment: What are you using to enable `import` syntax? Babel? Probably `import { default as sum } from "../sum";`

Comment: Es6 vs requirejs ?